# Add combined fields to Content type

Tags: 8

I'm creating a website with a Project content type. In that content type there are common fields and a few group fields. Group fields are fields that need to stay together and can be added multiple times. So in my Group fields there will be a date field and a text field that can be added multiple times.

Do I need to create a new content type or taxanomy type for this or is there a module for Drupal 8 that provides this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the module [field_collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection).

Add a field of type field_collection to your content type and allow multiple values. Then go to structure => Field collections and choose your field to add your date and text field.

**Update: field_collection is on its way to be deprecated**

Use [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module instead.

Notice these meta data issues for [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/node/2831131).

Comment: See this advice on the module page of field collection: Paragraphs is likely to replace field collection for Drupal 8. Field collection is on its way to being deprecated. It is recommended to use paragraphs instead of field collection for Drupal 8 projects.

Comment: Haven't seen it. I use field_collection on my own drupal 8 site and it works very well. So maybe I have to change to Paragraphs. I updated my answer.

Comment: You can check this meta issue for features that are not yet included in Paragraphs: https://www.drupal.org/node/2831131